# What symbols should be used for OCR and facial recognition actions?

Tags: symbols

What symbols should be used for OCR and facial recognition actions?

I think that I can use *camera* symbol for the face recognition,
but have no idea what I can use for OCR...

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific? A scenario might be helpful to understand what you want to do with those symbols.

Comment: @GildasFrémont Thanks. I made an iOS app, so I want to add most suitable icons for the bar buttons.

Comment: maybe just a button with <OCR> text on it?

Comment: @Ades I thought about it and I found it's a good idea, however I think many people haven't heard about OCR :) So, in a toastview on start I call it "Image to text conversion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think user oriented: you should find a way to make your app "smart" enough to recognize if it is an optical character recognition situation or a facial recognition one.

Let the user take a picture/use the lens and that is it. So camera icon is enough. Or an eye if its more a virtual reality experience.

[image]

**Show what is does not what it is nor how it is done.**

Comment: So, do you think it's OK now?(I updated post with a screenshot).

Comment: The camera icon should lead to: "take a picture"or "choose a picture in the phone". Recognition can be automatic I guess.

Comment: Recognition starts automatically(screen shows current video stream and if there is a face it will be recognized.

Comment: Then you are in the good direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

How about icons on buttons similar to the following for character recognition and face recognition respectively ....

[image]

[image]

Comment: magnifying glass implies search.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a Camera with face and camera with text respectively.

Comment: Thanks, probably this is the best answer. I'll make an icons and 'll check it out.